# How to disable Script on certain selected page

Tags: php

1st of all, its not Wordpress. Just PHP and HTML.

Is there any way to disable a few script on selected pages? I've saved all my custom script codes on scripts.js and serving it to all the pages in my site.

What I'm facing is conflicting issue. i.e. Login js code is having some issue with search js code.

I've searched all over the net but unable to find a solution. All I'm getting is for Wordpress with wp_enqueue. Is there any way to something like that? I mean disabling some script on selected pages?

jquery codes: http://pastebin.com/63eGKkCc

Comment: 1st of all, thank god!
How are we supposed to help without even seeing some code? What is wrong with people...

Comment: not only missing code... but why should it not be possible to load different scripts on different pages? whats holding you back?

Comment: It's neither _PHP_ or _HTML_, no code

Comment: @RichardBernards, So should I save different scripts for different pages? In that case, there will be so many pages of script. All I asked is there any easy way like any function or something like that?

Comment: @IronMaiden For the life of me, I do not understand what you are saying. Programming is not like waving a magic wand and everything does what you want... You should put your 'scripts' in their own sandbox and load only the necessary files on a certain page. Avoid duplication by including a file with reusable code... With your questions I can not be any clearer than this.

Comment: @IronMaiden Check in console, if there is any error then paste as it is in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its common problem if are using duplicate `ids` in different `scripts`.

For egs, if you are using `name` as id in `login script` and the same id is used in `search script`, so definately these 2 would create conflits with the same id `name`

Now, to reslove this you can have 2 options

1. Add unique `ids` to `elements` or access by using its `parent selector` like `$('#parent_unique_id #name')`
2. Add login script only to login page and search script to search page.

**Updated,** if you want to check the page and then add/run script then you can use `location.href` like,

```
if(location.href.indexOf('login')!==-1) { // for example its login.php page
     // code for login page
}
```

And do something like for `search page`.

Comment: _"Add login script only to login page and search script to search page."_ That's what he wants to know (how to implement).

Comment: Did you read this _1st of all, its not Wordpress. Just PHP and HTML._
If its simple `PHP` then obviously he had included login script and search script anywhere in the `php page`.

Comment: To my mind he's got a layout which contains all script and he wants to know: _"If it's search page, add this script, otherwise, if this is the login page add this script."_ But the only way he found it's by using `wp_enqueue` from WordPress. Maybe I'm missing the point.

Comment: Well, I've added the codes now. Can you check plz? @RohanKumar
And I guess @Debflav understand my issue, I'm not having any issue with `PHP`. Stuck on the rendering of `jquery conflict`.

Comment: It works on the login page. But for the search, it hasn't any fixed page. It is all over the site. Thanks for the idea. Cheers mate!